# Django throws {"non_field_errors":["Invalid data. Expected a dictionary, but got tuple."]} React JS

Tags: reactjs, django-rest-framework, jspdf, fetch-api, form-data

Trying to send file via fetch post from react to django rest,but got this django response shows:

> {"non_field_errors":["Invalid data. Expected a dictionary, but got tuple."]}

I am trying to send pdf generated file to django but unable to do, first I create pdf then send via fetch post request

**ReactJS**

```
 genPDF=(evt)=>{

    evt.preventDefault();
   html2canvas(document.getElementById("pdfid")).then(canvas=>{
       let img=canvas.toDataURL('img/png');
       let doc=new JsPDF();
       doc.addImage(img,'JPEG',30,30);
       doc.output('blob');
       //doc.save('test.pdf');
       let formdata=new FormData();
       formdata.append('file',doc);

       fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/chauffeur/pdf_upload/`,
           {
               method: 'POST',
               body:formdata,
           }
       ).then(response => response.json()).catch(error => console.error('Error:', error));

       //this.postpdf(formdata)
   });

};
```

**DJANGO**

```
class PdfUpload(APIView):

parser_classes = (MultiPartParser, FormParser,)

def get(self, request):
    return Response([PdfSerializer(file).data for file in Pdf.objects.all()])

def post(self,request):
    payload=(request.data,request.FILES)
    serializer=PdfSerializer(data=payload)

    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return Response("File Saved in Backend",status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    return Response(serializer.errors,status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

SERIALIZER.PY

```
class PdfSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

class Meta:
    model = Pdf
    fields = ['file',]
```

Am I send the a correct file because it PDF generated and then afterwards I send it through fetch request or It may be problem in formdata as at the django end it is expecting dictionary but formdata acting as tuple?

Comment: Where in the django code is the error thrown?

Comment: it actually gives in response

Comment: You should use some debugging techniques to find where the error happens in your django code. You can either run your app in a debugger or add `print()` statements.

Answer (score -1):

**Try this:**

```
formdata.append({'file':doc});
```

**Instead of**

```
formdata.append('file',doc);
```